# GKE nodes can't reach external IP hosted on the same GKE cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab-ci, google-kubernetes-engine

Running 1.11.2-gke.9 (COS image) 
I have installed installed gitlab-ci (including container registry) via helm chart. Everything is green.

Simple CI/Cd pipeline was pushing new images to gitlab docker registry. Push works.

On deployment - there is Error: ErrImagePull with

```
net/http: request canceled while waiting for connection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

After ssh'ing (gcp console ssh within browser) i noticed that the node can reach virtually the entire internet *but* not the very ingress the cluster is hosting.

Hence docker login/pull hanging.

How come that gitlab runner running inside GKE can push to registry, but the node that starts application pods cannot pull/login?

All FW rules are created by GKE itself, and they allow 80/443.

Routing quirk/bug?

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/HOaGQD4J8j0

Comment: In your comment, I see you are referring to [this group question](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/kubernetes-users/HOaGQD4J8j0). So, did the suggestion on updating the iptables for for in-cluster accesses solve your issue ? If yes, can you add the solution to your specific case in an answer here ?